# How to visualize/plot a graph in C++?

Tags: c++, graph

I just learned about Graphs and I want to plot them when I create them randomly.

How should I go about doing this?

EDIT:

I am talking about Graphs which are a collection of edges between vertices and not a plot of y=f(x).

Comment: Find a graphics library, and use it.  (C++ doesn't have a 'standard' graphics library)

Comment: The fact that there's is not yet graphics in the standard does not make the question bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what kind of graph? Directed graphs are different from scatter plots. 3D and/or 2D graphs?
Do you care whether it's c or c++?
Are you looking to write your own or are you looking for a library? There are LOTS of libraries, as a simple Google search would show.

If you want to create good, publication-quality graphs easily there are many standalone utilities like gnuplot, latex, R, mathematica etc. It is very easy to create a bad graph.

Comment: Sir I am a student and wish to learn something valuable. I would like it to be in C++. Also, plotting a graph is something I want to do just for fun and has no further use. What would you recommend?

I can spend a couple of weeks for this. So, should I write my own code or use libraries?

Comment: hmm.. if it's just for fun and you want to improve your knowledge of c++ then you might want to consider looking at the Boost graph library. Though i personally can't vouch for it's quality, Boost is considered the bleeding edge of c++ development. If you want to look at what a simple-yet-powerful interface might look like, dot might inspire you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language). It can be quite powerful to use a simple language to describe a graph and parse/display it with a c++ interpreter or compiler.

Comment: This is exactly the thing I needed to know. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to graphviz library. You can find it here: http://www.graphviz.org/ .

Answer (score 0):

One option is ROOT http://root.cern.ch/drupal/ from CERN. Examples: http://root.cern.ch/drupal/category/image-galleries/higgs-plots

Answer (score -2):

Checkout [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/), its open source, cross platform and easy to use.